# jQuery Validation Tool - Exact Text String Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know how to make a method within jQuery Validation Tool to require an exact text string? (upper/lowercase doesn't matter)

Also where does the method actually get placed?

-Brad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.validator.addMethod("mustBeFoo", function(value, element) {
    return (value.toLowerCase && (value.toLowerCase() === "foo"));
},
    "Must be foo!"
);
```

Put it anywhere. As long as it runs before validation, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can also match multiple strings like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("statecheck", function(value, element) {
    return (value.toLowerCase && (value.toLowerCase() === "nsw" || value.toLowerCase() === "act" || value.toLowerCase() === "nt" || value.toLowerCase() === "qld" || value.toLowerCase() === "sa" || value.toLowerCase() === "tas" || value.toLowerCase() === "vic" || value.toLowerCase() === "wa"));
},
    "Please enter valid state"
);
```